# Clarification on Rank-Nullity Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I'm reading lecture notes from a course on applciations of polynomials in extremal combinatorics, where I came across a proof involving the use of the rank-nullity theorem, and wasn't sure how to interpret part of it:

Let $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ represent the $n$-dimensional field with $q$ elements, and $poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)$ be the space of all polynomials with degree $\leq{D}$ in the ring $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$.

Theorem: Given a set $S\subset{\mathbb{F}_q^n}$, if $dim(poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n))>|S|$, there exists a polynomial $P\in{poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)}$ that vanishes on all points of $S$.

Proof: Suppose $dim(poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n))>|S|$. Define the set $S\subset{\mathbb{F}^n}$ to have points $({p_1,...,{p_{|S|}}})$. Let there be an evaluation mapping $E:poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)\rightarrow{\mathbb{F}^{|S|}}$ defined by $E(Q)=(Q(p_1),...,Q(p_{|S|}))$. Given that $E$ is a linear mapping, by the rank nullity theorem, $E$ has a non-trivial kernel, meaning that there exists at least one non-zero polynomial $P\in{poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)}$ that vanishes on $S$.

I'm not sure why we are able to state that $P\neq{0}$. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was no such non-zero $P$, the kernel would be trivial.  But, it is not by rank-nullity.

If it is the previous clause--the application of the rank-nullity--that's confusing, let me know.

Comment: So $0$ mapping to $0$ isn't ever counted as part of the kernel?

Comment: It is, but the kernel must be at least 1-dimensional here.  That's where rank-nullity happened.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot.